# Starting my app at 9a.m. and end at 7 p.m

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I have a timed start/end requirement

- I need to start my app at 9a.m.
- Stop my application at 7p.m.

I have used AlarmManager class for the same but unable to trigger my app at 9a.m.

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long durationTime = 3 * 60 * 1000;
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime + durationTime, durationTime, pintent);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Popping up an app at a set time is probably not a good idea (unless it is an alarm clock). If you are trying to limit when it runs, just check the time from inside the app and `finish()` if not inside the allowed period.

Comment: What is the problem ? No one is going to copy your code to test it out. Please make it easy to understand.